# Creating Google AppScript form submit triggers without violating quotas?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

I work in an areas with about ~200 school based collaborators and we all have access to the same Google domain. Using Google AppScript (that pulls from a Google Spreadsheet generated by a python cron job), I am programmatically creating a pre-conference form that is custom-developed to each of the schools, yielding me about 200 forms. This all works fine.

I need to attach a trigger on the submission of each of these forms. I have it written and tested the function. All works fine.

The problem is I cannot propagate the submission logic to all of the forms because of the 20 triggers / user / script quota limit. Each of these forms is only going to have 1 response, and it would make sense to me that I should be able to have 1 trigger / form (I will definitely be under the 6 hrs/day processing limit for triggers).

So, this issue is occurring because the AppScript trigger limit is in terms of the code that is being called with the trigger and not the Form that is triggering it. Is there another way to set up the Google services to avoid this quota? I can be flexible and I've already created a batch service to create the forms without violating the 6 minute maximum execution time, but it seems like any attempt to have one script creating more than 20 forms with 1 trigger will lead to failure.

Comment: What is the form trigger doing? You can create a single [onFormSubmit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) in Sheets and attach multiple forms to it. If not that, then a [clock trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) that checks all form responses every hour etc